# how to make google map coordinates request more precise/accurate with c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, coordinates

Im building a winform project using Google maps api. im sending an address and i get the address coordinates as a result. However, im not getting the most accurate results...
here is my code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace WinForm_Project
{
   class GoogleMaps
   {
       public static GeoResponse GetGeoCodedResults(string address) and uses google maps to retrieve the address's coordinates. 
       {
           string url = string.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&region=dk&sensor=false",HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address));
           var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
           request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
           request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
           DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GeoResponse));
           var res = (GeoResponse)serializer.ReadObject(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
           return res;
       }
   }
}
```

this part works just fine. (just to be clear - my winform app does not contain a google map) 
i noticed when i type an address on google maps's website i get certain coordinates - but the coordinates (Latitude, longitude) become more accurate when i zoom-in...

is there a way to change the request\code to get from google a more accurate results? such as **Max** zoom-in will display on google maps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google's JSON option, your result will contain something like this.

```
...
"geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 40.91525559999999,
              "lng" : -73.70027209999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.495908,
              "lng" : -74.2590879
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 40.7143528,
           "lng" : -74.00597309999999
...
```

The exact 'point' will be under results-->geometry-->location.  However, if your query is an area, say New York City, then you will get a bounding box for that area (results-->geometry-->bounds).  If that's the case, the exact location given would probably be the center of that area or a commonly accepted point.

Comment: The result i get is in this format exactly. the thing is that i thought the cordinates ("Location") is more accurate (Latitude, longitude) if u zoom in first - but i guess is not correct... Thank's for your trouble

Comment: I noticed in my area that Google started returning address points points suitable for driving directions. They used to return points of "ROOFTOP" accuracy on the buildings but the points are now in the street. I had to switch to Bing API which still returns rooftops under UsageType, Display.